# How do I know if I am using ARM using Windows API?

Tags: c, windows

How do I check if the system on which my program is running on is an arm based or not using c/c++?

Comment: If you're using C or C++ then your compiler will tell you.

Comment: runtime @WeatherVane

Comment: Is it really necessary to do it runtime? Don't you already know this at compile time? And that information won't change from compile time to runtime, at least usually won't change.

Comment: @theprogrammer: If an **ARM binary** is executed, you know you are running on ARM. No need for additional indicator. Detecting the target architecture is only relevant at compile-time to use platform-dependent code.

Comment: Well, Windows 10 can run fully fledged programs on ARM (Source: Their official YouTube channel). So maybe that's what OP has in mind? But it's irrelevant, since that update is not yet released to public.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/apps-on-arm
"Windows 10 on ARM can also run your x86 Win32 apps unmodified, with good performance and a seamless user experience, just like any PC. These x86 Win32 apps don’t have to recompiled for ARM and don’t even realize they are running on an ARM processor. Note that 64-bit x64 Win32 apps are not supported, but the vast majority of apps have x86 versions available."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{

    SYSTEM_INFO SystemInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&SystemInfo);

    if(SystemInfo.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ARM)
    {
        // System's processor is ARM based
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: As Anders suggested, use `GetNativeSystemInfo` for better and accurate results.

Comment: what is SYSTEM_INFO?? Is it a new data type?

Comment: Windows Dev Center: [Getting Hardware Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724423(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `SYSTEM_INFO` is a struct. It's defined as `typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO { .. } SYSTEM_INFO`.

Comment: GetSystemInfo is probably the wrong function, it probably lies if you are a x86 running under emulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if you are compiling for ARM then you can check if [`_M_ARM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)  is defined.

If you are a x86 application and you want to know if you are running emulated on a ARM machine (not actually possible yet but [maybe soon](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/11/x86-emulation-rumored-to-be-coming-to-windows-for-arm-in-late-2017/)?) then you would call [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340(v=vs.85).aspx) and check the `wProcessorArchitecture` field.

You should not call `GetSystemInfo` as suggested in the other answer because it is most likely going to lie and return PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL when x86 apps run on ARM.